# Callback или Promise как правильно дождаться результата функции?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback

Мне нужно дождаться чтобы **result** был не **null**
Я использую цикл **for** но хочу сделать это как-то лучше, как это можно сделать через промис и есть ли в этом смысл? Подскажи варианты. Полученый результат использую в другой функции.

```
    const fetch = require('node-fetch')
  getLinkToConfirmRegistration: async (email, typeLink = "reg", page) => {
    const partsEmail = email.split("@");
    let result;
    for (const i of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) {
      await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
      result = await fetch(
        `https://www.1secmail.com/api/v1/?action=getMessages&login=${partsEmail[0]}&domain=${partsEmail[1]}`
      ).then((res) => res.json());
      if (result !== null) {
        break;
      } else if (i === 5 && result === null) {
        throw new Error(`Emails are not sent`);
      }
    }
    try {
      const link = await fetch(
        `https://www.1secmail.com/api/v1/?action=readMessage&login=${partsEmail[0]}&domain=${partsEmail[1]}&id=${result[0].id}`
      ).then((res) => res.json());
      if (typeLink === "template") {
        return link;
      }
      if (typeLink !== "reg") {
        const re = /(https?:\/\/\S+\w)/g;
        const nameList = link.textBody.match(re);
        return nameList[0];
      }
      const words = link.body.match(/(".*?")/);
      const clearLink = words[0].replace(/"/g, "");
      return clearLink;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return null;
    }
  },
```

Comment: Я вижу, вы fetch вызываете в контексте Node.js, а не в контексте браузера. Это функция какой-то библиотеки?

Comment: я использую const fetch = require('node-fetch')

Comment: выложил функцию полностью,хочу улучшить её...

Comment: Если вам нужно ограничить количество попыток и разделить их таймаутами, ваш вариант вполне приемлемый. Если вы хотите найти альтернативы, уточните, что вас не устраивает или каких улучшений вы хотите добиться — тогда желающим будет легче что-то подсказать.

Comment: а при чём тут puppeteer? а зачем тут page.waitForTimeout? а может fetch на самом деле выполняется в контексте evaluate?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ нет не в контексте evaluate,зачем waitForTimeout? Просто использую как ожидание.

Comment: vsemozhebuty . Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для доступа к api бы сделал "клиента" в котором бы инкапсулировал всё необходимое для общения с сервисом:

```
// @ts-check
const { default: fetch } = require('node-fetch');
const { URL, URLSearchParams } = require('url');

const sleep = (timeout = 1000) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, timeout));

/**
 * @param {string} email
 * @param {'template' | 'reg'} [typeLink='reg']
 */
async function getLinkToConfirmRegistration(email, typeLink = 'reg') {
  const client = new OneSecMailClient(email);
  
  let count = 100;
  let messages;
  while (count--) {
    try {
      messages = await client.action('getMessages');
      if (messages && Array.isArray(messages) && messages.length > 0) {
        break;
      }
      await sleep();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  let lastMessage;
  if (messages && Array.isArray(messages) && messages.length > 0) {
    lastMessage = await client.action('readMessage', { id: messages[0].id });
  }
  if (!lastMessage) {
    throw new Error(`Emails are not sent`);
  }

  console.log(lastMessage.textBody);
}

class OneSecMailClient {
  #endpoint = 'https://www.1secmail.com/api/v1/';
  #login
  #domain

  /**
   * @param {string} email
   * @memberof OneSecMailClient
   */
  constructor(email) {
    [ this.#login, this.#domain ] = email.split('@');
  }

  async action(actionName, param = {}) {
    const url = new URL(this.#endpoint);
    url.search = new URLSearchParams({
      action: actionName,
      login: this.#login,
      domain: this.#domain,
      ...param
    }).toString();

    const res = await fetch(
      url.toString(),
      {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      }
    );

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(res.statusText || `Status: ${res.status}`);
    }

    return res.json();
  }
}


(async () => {

  const email = 'ldus8o76uq@esiix.com';
  await getLinkToConfirmRegistration(email, 'reg');

})();
```

Этот код можно проверить, запустив его и отправив письмо на указанный email:

```bsh
mail -s 'subject' ldus8o76uq@esiix.com <<< 'testing message body'
```

---

Я люблю использовать [библиотеку p-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-retry) для организации чего-то *асинхронного и повторяемого*, - она сделает наш код ещё нагляднее:

```
// @ts-check
const pRetry = require('p-retry');
const { default: fetch } = require('node-fetch');
const { URL, URLSearchParams } = require('url');

const sleep = (timeout = 1000) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, timeout));

/**
 * @param {string} email
 * @param {'template' | 'reg'} [typeLink='reg']
 */
async function getLinkToConfirmRegistration(email, typeLink = 'reg') {
  const client = new OneSecMailClient(email);

  const messages = await pRetry(
    async () => {
      const list = await client.action('getMessages');
      return Array.isArray(list) && list.length > 0 ? list : Promise.reject(new Error('Emails are not sent'));
    },
    {
      retries: 100,
      factor: 1
    }
  );

  const lastMessage = await client.action('readMessage', { id: messages[0].id });
  console.log(lastMessage.textBody);
}

class OneSecMailClient {
  #endpoint = 'https://www.1secmail.com/api/v1/';
  #login
  #domain

  /**
   * @param {string} email
   * @memberof OneSecMailClient
   */
  constructor(email) {
    [ this.#login, this.#domain ] = email.split('@');
  }

  async action(actionName, param = {}) {
    const url = new URL(this.#endpoint);
    url.search = new URLSearchParams({
      action: actionName,
      login: this.#login,
      domain: this.#domain,
      ...param
    }).toString();

    const res = await fetch(
      url.toString(),
      {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      }
    );

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(res.statusText || `Status: ${res.status}`);
    }

    return res.json();
  }
}


(async () => {

  const email = 'ldus9o76uq@esiix.com';
  await getLinkToConfirmRegistration(email, 'reg');

})();
```